# Склейка 16-битного числа из двух 8-битных частей

Tags: c#, vb.net

Получаю из COM Port `20` и `3` например. `20` это в двоичном `00010100` и `3` это в двоичном `00000011`.

Склеиваем `0000001100010100` = результат в десятичном формате `788`.

Как мне получить результат такого вида?

Comment: 3 * 256 + 20 = 788

Comment: `c = a + (b << 8)`

Comment: Два правильных ответа и оба в комментариях. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 3):

Умножение на 2<sup>8</sup>=256 для сдвига влево на 8 бит

`3 * 256 + 20 = 788`

Сдвиг влево с арифметическим сложением

`c = a + (b << 8)`

Сдвиг влево с побитовым сложением "ИЛИ"

`c = a | (b << 8)`

Comment: А разве не последний байт нужно просто приплюсовать?

Comment: @こきん почему нет?